# want to redirect to next page with same id

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a flight application. I want to redirect to page containing data same to one flight i select. I redirect from one page to other where containing flights and the flights redirect to hotels containing data same to flight. Now i want to take the same page data to third page containing select date. I am not sure how to do that

**This page contains flight data i am getting using Stream Builder and making parameter of Document Snapshot**

```
import 'package:bpe_application/dum.dart';
import 'package:bpe_application/home/dumy.dart';
import 'package:bpe_application/home/flight.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';


class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Widget list() {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("flights").snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            DocumentSnapshot dc = snapshot.data!.docs [index];
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(16),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(16),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment:
                              MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [

                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 100,
                                  child:
                                  Text(
                                    "From",
                                    style: GoogleFonts.limelight(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 11,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),

                                GestureDetector(
                                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_right,size: 35,),
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) =>Flight(
                                              dc: snapshot.data!.docs[index],
                                            )));
                                  },
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 9),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: Text(
                                  dc['from'],
                                  style: GoogleFonts.limelight(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 13,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 16,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 13),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment:
                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 100,
                                child: Text(
                                  dc['city1'],
                                  style: GoogleFonts.limelight(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 11,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                            width: 10,
                            child: DecoratedBox(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                                color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: LayoutBuilder(
                                builder: (context, constraints) {
                                  return Flex(
                                    children: List.generate(
                                        (constraints.constrainWidth() / 10)
                                            .floor(),
                                            (index) => SizedBox(
                                          height: 1,
                                          width: 5,
                                          child: DecoratedBox(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors
                                                    .grey.shade300),
                                          ),
                                        )),
                                    direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: Icon(Icons.watch_later_outlined),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                            width: 10,
                            child: DecoratedBox(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10)),
                                color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 110,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(16),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(16)),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 12, 0, 8),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment:
                              MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 100,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "To",
                                    style: GoogleFonts.limelight(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 13),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  dc['to'],
                                  style: GoogleFonts.limelight(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 13,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 16,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 11),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment:
                              MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 100,
                                  child: Text(
                                    dc['city2'],
                                    style: GoogleFonts.limelight(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 11,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                  ],
                ),
              )
            );
          },
        )
            : Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, //top bar color
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black, //bottom bar color
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    ));
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        title: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70, 0, 0, 0),
          child: Text("Flights",
          style: GoogleFonts.limelight(
            color: Colors.white
          ),),
        ),
      ),
      body: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
          topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0),
        ),
        child: Container(
          height: 800.0,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.grey.shade200,
           child: list(),
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

**This page where i redirect first the hotel detail page**

```
 class Flight extends StatefulWidget {
      final dc;
      Flight({required this.dc});
    
      @override
      State<Flight> createState() => _FlightState();
    }
    
    class _FlightState extends State<Flight> {
      final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      var name = '';
      var location = '';
      var price = '';
      var review = '';
      var description = '';
      var total = '';
      book() async {
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Book')
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
            .set({
              'from': widget.dc.get('from'),
              'to': widget.dc.get('to'),
              'city1': widget.dc.get('city1'),
              'city2': widget.dc.get('city2'),
              'name': name,
              'location': location,
              'price': price,
              'review': review,
              'description': description,
              'total': total
            })
            .then((value) => print('User Added'))
            .catchError((error) => print('Falied to add user: $error'));
      }
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, //top bar color
          systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black, //bottom bar color
          systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        ));
        return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            appBar: AppBar(
              elevation: 0.0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              title: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70, 0, 0, 0),
                child: Text(
                  "Flights",
                  style: GoogleFonts.limelight(
                    fontSize: 25,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            body: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('AddHotel')
                    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                    .get(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    print('somthing went wrong');
                  }
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }
                  var data = snapshot.data;
                  name = data!['name'];
                  location = data['location'];
                  price = data['price'];
                  review = data['review'];
                  description = data['description'];
                  total = data['total'];
    
                  return ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                      topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                                height: 40,
                                width: 320,
                                child: FlatButton(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                  ),
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 218, 162, 16),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      book();
                                    });
                                    Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) => Calender(
                                              dc: snapshot.data!.docs[index] ,
                                            )));
                                  },
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Book",
                                      style: GoogleFonts.limelight(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }));
      }
    }
```

I just want to know here in hotel details page how can i make the DocumentSnapshot parameter to pass as constructor to Calender Screen

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

"**DocumentSnapshot dc** = snapshot.data!.docs [index];"

over hear "dc: snapshot.data!.docs[index]," *"dc: **dc**"

```
 class Flight extends StatefulWidget {
  final DocumentSnapshot dc;
  Flight({required this.dc});

  @override
  State<Flight> createState() => _FlightState();
}


  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Book')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .set({
          'from': widget.dc['from'],
          'to': widget.dc['to'],
          'city1': widget.dc['city1'],
          'city2': widget.dc['city2'],
          'name': name,
          'location': location,
          'price': price,
          'review': review,
          'description': description,
          'total': total
        })
        .then((value) => print('User Added'))
        .catchError((error) => print('Falied to add user: $error'));
```